# Console log ({value}) isn't the same as console.log(value)

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I'm not stuck or anything, it's just my own curiosity and I noticed something about Console.log,
And I can't find anwsers online , or its limited since I think making a Google search with "{}" isn't really working out

I'm coding a small node.Js app that interacts with Wi-Fi, and I tried the following thing :

```
console.log(ssid +  " : " + pwd);
```

and it returns this

```
freebox_XXXXX : fake_password
```

So far, everything is normal but then, I was tired and messed up and tried this :

```
console.log({ ssid: ssid, password: pwd });
```

and it returned this

```
 {
  ssid: 'f\x00r\x00e\x00e\x00b\x00o\x00x\x00_\x005\x007\x00a\x002\x00a\x007\x00',
  password: '\x00T\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00'
 }
```

I'm wondering why do you have any answers?

More details :

The data sent via bluetooth by this function as an bufferArray is created with this function

```js
str2ab(str) {
    let buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2); // 2 bytes for each char
    let bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
      bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
  }
let payload = str2ab('freebox_XXXXX|' + alertData.password);
```

Then, the other devices receives it

```js
WriteOnlyCharacteristic.prototype.onWriteRequest = function(data, offset, withoutResponse, callback) {
    let payload = data.toString()

    let wifiData = payload.split('|');

    let ssid = wifiData[0];
    let pwd = wifiData[1];
    console.log(ssid +  " : " + pwd);
    console.log({ ssid: ssid, password: pwd });

   });
```

Comment: When you wrap it in `{}` you are creating a literal object and adding properties to it. This `ssid +  " : " + pwd` is just string concatination

Comment: @Rajesh That does not answer why Node.js is displaying NULLs in objects and not in strings

Comment: Oh alright, I get it now, but why is it turning strings into unicode ?

Comment: @DizioAdil JS strings are already unicode

Comment: @Tibebes.M Just press before `const { ssid, password: pwd } = {
  ssid: 'f\x00r\x00e\x00e\x00b\x00o\x00x\x00_\x005\x007\x00a\x002\x00a\x007\x00',
  password: '\x00T\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00'
 }`;

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I do not see `null`. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Rajesh `'\0'` (or `'\x00'`) is the null character, ASCII value 0

Comment: @Rajesh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I did not know that. Do you think its some formatting issue in input? as you see `freebox` but its filled with `\x00` after every character

Comment: The issue is obvious: for some reason, Node.js ignores special characters in strings in `console.log()` but not in objects. The question is _why_

Comment: BTW, the same thing does not reproduce on Chrome nor in Firefox

Comment: @DizioAdil could you share how you are accepting credentials?

Comment: @Rajesh Done ! I hope it'll help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is because of how Node.js logs values.

The behaviour of `console.log()` depends on the type of values being logged:

- If a *string* is logged, it is written to *stdout* as-is (well, not as-is, because `%`-args are substituted, but that's off-topic for this question), to allow raw texts (optionally with escape sentences) to be displayed in the console
- If *another data type* is passed, it will be inspected (intended for debugging, the same way as [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) does it), that is, it will be converted to a format nearly identical to the JS syntax that created it. **That makes the strings inside complex data structures displayed as their representation: with quotes around them and special characters escaped.**

Your strings contain NULL characters between each letter (that's probably because your code treats a UTF-16 string as UTF-8 or ASCII somewhere), which don't appear when logged to the console, but show up escaped (`\x00`) when the string is inspected.

That is the cause of the inconsistency between the two logging methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ ssid: ssid, password: pwd }
```

It is a object not string.